# Apache SOLR exception with 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: solr

I am intermittently getting this exception from SOLR and unable to reproduce in lower environments. Please advise if anyone has gone through similar issues:

org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://internal-mci-prod-2049632463.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:8082/solr/collection2: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html.  502 Bad Gateway

## 502 Bad Gateway

at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:629) at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:265) at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:248) at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:211) at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:228) at gov.state.nextgen.mdm.service.SolrUtility.querySolr(SolrUtility.java:363) at gov.state.nextgen.mdm.service.SolrUtility.deleteDocumentById(SolrUtility.java:432) at gov.state.nextgen.mdm.service.UpdateClientServiceImpl.updateClientDetails(UpdateClientServiceImpl.java:408) at gov.state.nextgen.mdm.service.UpdateClientServiceImpl.process(UpdateClientServiceImpl.java:152) at gov.state.nextgen.mdm.controller.UpdateClientController.updateClient(UpdateClientController.java:29) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor384.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

This works fine in most cases, but randomly fails. So unable to identify the root cause.

Comment: That's generally caused by something in front of your application, for example a AWS load balancer/cache/etc.